# Shapefile to Mysql error using ogr2ogr

Tags: shapefile, gdal, ogr2ogr, mysql, homebrew

I'm following [this tutorial](http://victorwyee.com/webapp/creating-country-polygon-locator-php-mysql-google-maps/). I installed the “GDAL Complete” Framework from kyngchaos.com and I tested the installation on Mac. I have GDAL 1.11.2, released 2015/02/10.

When I am trying to run this command:

```
ogr2ogr -f MySQL MySQL:dbname,user=root,password=password \
      -nln world_borders -nlt MULTIPOLYGON \
      -update -overwrite \
      -lco ENGINE=MyISAM \
      -lco MYSQL_FID=ogr_fid -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geometry \
      /path/to/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp
```

With my settings it would be:

```
ogr2ogr -f MySQL MySQL:mapas,user=xxxx,password=xxxx \
      -nln test -nlt MULTIPOLYGON \
      -update -overwrite \
      -lco ENGINE=MyISAM \
      -lco MYSQL_FID=ogr_fid -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geometry \
      /Users/Seph/Downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp
```

I got this error:

```
Unable to find driver `MySQL'.
The following drivers are available:
-> `ESRI Shapefile'
-> `MapInfo File'
-> `UK .NTF'
-> `SDTS'
-> `TIGER'
-> `S57'
-> `DGN'
-> `VRT'
-> `REC'
```

I have created the table on my database before running the command.

**UPDATE**
I installed Homebrew I and ran this command:

```
brew install gdal --with-mysql
```

Now I have the supported format:  -> "MySQL" (read/write)

But now I have this error:

```
Macbook-pro:~ Seph$ ogr2ogr -f MySQL MySQL:mapas,user=xxxx,password=xxxx\
      -nln test -nlt MULTIPOLYGON \
      -update -overwrite \
      -lco ENGINE=MyISAM \
      -lco MYSQL_FID=ogr_fid -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geometry \
       /Users/Seph/Downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp
      ERROR 1: MySQL connect failed for: mapas,user=xxxx,password=xxxx
      Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
      ERROR 1: MySQL connect failed for: mapas,user=xxxx,password=xxxx
      Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
      ERROR 1: MySQL connect failed for: mapas,user=xxxx,password=xxxx
      Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
      ERROR 1: MySQL driver doesn't currently support database creation.
      Please create database before using.
      MySQL driver failed to create MySQL:mapas,user=xxxx,password=xxxx
```

I am using phpMyAdmin from Xammp

Comment: does "MySQL" appear when you run: ogrinfo --formats ?

Comment: Hi, No, It doesn't

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been 5 months since this question was posted, but I thought I'd add in my $.02.  I, too, had the problem of `ogr2ogr` not being able to connect.

In my case, it turned out that `ogr2ogr` expects the `mysql.sock` file to be in `/tmp/`.  If you're running MAMP, your sock file is actually located in `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`.  Creating a symlink fixed the issue for me:

```
ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/
```

Also, if you're using Postgres.app AND gdal, be aware that you'll have two versions of `ogr2ogr` installed.  Updating my `.bash_profile` to look for the version installed via `brew install gdal --with-mysql` did the trick:

```
alias ogr2ogr=/usr/local/bin/ogr2ogr
```

Place that *above* the PATH directive so it overrides the `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin` path include that should be in your PATH variable.

I mention this because @jmcboom asked you to run `ogrinfo`.  If, like me, you did that and got no MySQL driver, it is probably because the `ogrinfo` you're running is looking at the Postgres.app version, not your brew version.

I hope this helps.

Cheers,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

```
ogr2ogr **-F** MySQL MySQL:mapas,user=xxxx,password=xxxx \
      -nln test -nlt MULTIPOLYGON \
      -update -overwrite \
      -lco ENGINE=MyISAM \
      -lco MYSQL_FID=ogr_fid -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geometry \
      /Users/Seph/Downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp
```

The letter f has to be capitalized.

Comment: ..this is not correct. That `f` is lower-case in 100% of the ogr2ogr instructions I have saved for reuse since I've had my current job. Because you're new and I want to welcome you to the community I'll refrain from down-voting so as not to set you back, but this is unfortunately not correct ..that is, unless this is a unique issue with the Mac build, which I doubt.